# How to add space in ionic select place holder which is having dynamic values

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want space In between flag And name which are dynamic values and I tried with   but nbsp printing in between them.How to add Space between them?

Comment: Can you share some code, like relevant ts and html parts?

Comment: <ion-select Placeholder ={{country}}{{flag}}>  ..I have like this

Comment: Have you tried with `placeholder="{{country}} {{flag}}"`?

Comment: Yes then showing error the other part is being separated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely doing something wrong, probably not putting quotes around placeholder values, because

`<ion-select placeholder="{{firstString}} {{secondString}}">`

definitely displays a space between two strings: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-ocsyqd